# Passing the values of my radio buttons into an array

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button

I am looking to get the value of a selected radio button from my Quiz into an array. Currently I am having issues with this even though I am echoing the selected value on the Quiz Page itself and it correctly identifies which one was selected. However when the user is taken to the results page the array will not store any of the values that the user has selected previous.

LoadQuiz.php Code

```
<?php 

session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","root","usbw","degreeproject");

$quizid = $_GET['quizid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE QuizID = '$quizid'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$_SESSION['quiz'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['Question'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['CorrectAnswer'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer1'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer2'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer3'] = Array();
$_SESSION['quiz']['SelectedAnswers'] = Array(); 
$_SESSION['quizlength'] = $result->num_rows;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$_SESSION['quiz']['Question'][] = $row['Question'];
$_SESSION['quiz']['CorrectAnswer'][] = $row['CorrectAnswer'];
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer1'][] = $row['IncorrectAnswer1'];
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer2'][] = $row['IncorrectAnswer2'];
$_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer3'][] = $row['IncorrectAnswer3'];
}

if($_SESSION['quizlength'] > 0)
{
header("location: quiz.php?page=1");
}
else
{
echo("Error loading quiz");
}

?>
```

Quiz.php Code

```
<?php 

session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","root","usbw","degreeproject");

$pageid = $_GET['page'];
$nextpage = $pageid + 1;



if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{   
if($_GET['Answer'] == $_GET['CorrectAnswer'])
{
    $_SESSION['quiz']['SelectedAnswers'][$pageid-2] = 1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['quiz']['SelectedAnswers'][$pageid-2] = 0;

}
}
$Question = $_SESSION['quiz']['Question'][$pageid-1];
$CAnswer = $_SESSION['quiz']['CorrectAnswer'][$pageid-1];
$IAnswer1 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer1'][$pageid-1];
$IAnswer2 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer2'][$pageid-1];
$IAnswer3 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer3'][$pageid-1];




if($pageid < $_SESSION['quizlength'])
{


echo("<form action='quiz.php?page=".$nextpage."'>");



}
else
{

    echo("<form action='quizresults.php'>");
}


if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{

$SAnswer = $_GET['Answer'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$SAnswer; 

}

echo("<br>$Question,
<form> 
<br>$CAnswer
<input type='radio' name='Answer' value= '$CAnswer' > 
<br>$IAnswer1
<input type='radio' name='Answer' value= '$IAnswer1' > 
<br>$IAnswer2
<input type='radio' name='Answer' value= '$IAnswer2' > 
<br>$IAnswer3
<input type='radio' name='Answer' value= '$IAnswer3' >
<br>$pageid
<input type='hidden' name='page' value='$nextpage' >");
echo("<input type='submit' value='Select Answer' name='submit'>");
echo("</form>");





?>
```

QuizResults.php Code

```
<?php 

session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3307","root","usbw","degreeproject");

if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
echo("U " . $_SESSION["username"]);
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
}

else
{
header("location:login.php");
}




$Question = $_SESSION['quiz']['Question'];
$CAnswer = $_SESSION['quiz']['CorrectAnswer'];
$IAnswer1 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer1'];
$IAnswer2 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer2'];
$IAnswer3 = $_SESSION['quiz']['IncorrectAnswer3'];
$SAnswers = $_SESSION['quiz']['SelectedAnswers'];
print_r($_SESSION['quiz']);

$QuizTaken = TRUE;

if($QuizTaken==TRUE)
{
echo("<br>The Question Asked Was: ");
echo($Question = $_SESSION['quiz']['Question'][0]);
echo("<br>The Correct Answer Was: ");
echo($CAnswer = $_SESSION['quiz']['CorrectAnswer'][0]);
echo("<br>The Answer You Gave Was: ");
echo($SAnswers  = $_SESSION['quiz']['SelectedAnswers'][0]);


}

else

{

echo("NO QUIZ HAS BEEN TAKEN");

}






?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.